# Override the equality operators with Equals()

Tags: c#, operators, overriding, equality

I've been debugging an issue for quite some time and realize that it was coming from the usage of an `==` on a object where I should have used the `object.Equals()`

In order to prevent such issue, would like that the `==` operator calls the `Object.Equals()` that I have overridden.

Is that possible? The following code runs into a Stack-overflow exception...

```
public static bool operator ==(Portfolio a, Portfolio b)
{
    return a != null && a.Equals(b);
}

public static bool operator !=(Portfolio a, Portfolio b)
{
    return a != null && !a.Equals(b);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: And how does your `Equals` looks like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're recursively calling the `!=` operator from your `!=` operator, hence the stack overflow. Use `ReferenceEquals` instead:

```
public static bool operator !=(Portfolio a, Portfolio b)
{
    return !object.ReferenceEquals(a, null) && !a.Equals(b);
}
```

That said, this code is flawed because it'll return `false` if `a` is null and `b` isn't. You should check both objects for null:

```
public static bool operator !=(Portfolio a, Portfolio b)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, null))
    {
        return !object.ReferenceEquals(b, null);
    }

    return !a.Equals(b);
}
```

Comment: Usually I like to make one `private/protected static bool Equals([type] a, [type] b) { if (ReferenceEquals(a, b)) { return true; } if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) || ReferenceEquals(b, null)) { return false; } /* logic knowing a and b are not NullReferences */ }` and then `public override bool Equals(object obj) { return Equals(this, obj as [type]); }` and `public static bool operator ==([type] a, [type] b) { return Equals(a, b); }` and `public static bool operator !=([type] a, [type] b) { return !Equals(a, b); }`

Comment: And if the type should be comparable, I go with this approach: https://ericlippert.com/2013/10/07/math-from-scratch-part-six-comparisons/

Comment: Hi. Thanks! Actually came up with the same solution at the same time :)